# Flutter integration test not working when build for testlab (iOS with schema)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-test-lab, flutter-integration-test

How are you? I’m trying to configure Testlab for ios, but I’m having problems with the configuration.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/main/packages/integration_test#ios-device-testing

When following the documentation recommended by Firebase when executing the `xcodebuild build-for-testing` command, code breaks because it does not find some frameworks.

Script

```
output="../build/ios_integ"
product="build/ios_integ/Build/Products"

Pass --simulator if building for the simulator.
flutter build ios integration_test/authentication/test/sign_in_co_test.dart --flavor qa --dart-define=flavor=qa --release


pushd ios
xcodebuild build-for-testing \
  -workspace Runner.xcworkspace \
  -scheme qa \
  -xcconfig Flutter/Release.xcconfig \
  -configuration Release \
  -derivedDataPath \
  $output -sdk iphoneos


xcodebuild test-without-building \
  -xctestrun "../build/ios_integ/Build/Products/qa_iphoneos16.2-arm64.xctestrun" \
  -destination id=<device-id>
popd
```

[image]

To give a momentary solution to this, I copy the modules manually and there it allows me to execute the code correctly. However, later I try to run the test build locally and the test fails with the following error.

[image]

Thanks a lot for read and try to help me . :pray:

run flutter test on testlab (ios with schema).

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on sending Flutter iOS tests to Firebase Test Labs and am having issues. I have ran into the same issue with the GeneratedPluginRegistrant not being able to find a module in a project that contains flavors/schemas apart from Runner and have fixed it by specifying a correct build configuration.

Running `xcodebuild -list` in the ios directory will list all build configurations, targets, and schemas for your project. Select the appropriate build configuration and pass it in to the parameter `-configuration \` in your script.

Let me know if that helps out.